# Class already in use exception

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to use SonataAdminBundle and SonataUserBundle on my symfony4 project. When I try to extend SonataUserBundle, I got an error states that my new class is already in use:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonat
aUserBundle, because the name is already in use in C:\wamp64\www\staff-test\src\
Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle.php on line 24
```

I enable the bundle on bundles.php file
On composer.json file, I added my new bundle on psr4 attribute.
I mapped my new bundle on doctrine
My ApplicationSonataUserBundle class is used just in my Bundle. I extended it :

```
php bin/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle --dest=src --namespace_prefix=App
```

My Bundles.php file :

```
return [
    Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Application\\":"src/Application/"
        }
    },
```

doctrine.yaml

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
```

ApplicationSonataUserBundle class:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the SonataEasyExtendsBundle.
 *
 * @link https://sonata-project.org/easy-extends
 *
 * References:
 * @link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/bundles.html
 */
class ApplicationSonataUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'SonataUserBundle';
    }
}
```

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.5",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.4",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.48",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.8",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.3",
        "symfony/acl-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/process": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
    },
```

I need just to extend SonataUserBundle, but everytime I try to do it, I have the same problem. I'm using Symfony4 in my project. The exception appears after extending the bundle.

Any idea about this problem? I posted the problem before but no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve problem. I just added App on my namespace :

```
namespace App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the SonataEasyExtendsBundle.
 *
 * @link https://sonata-project.org/easy-extends
 *
 * References:
 * @link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/bundles.html
 */
class ApplicationSonataUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'SonataUserBundle';
    }
}
```

And in bundles.php too :

```
return [
    App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```